# Access to mobile calendar in Salesforce1 app

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, calendar

I am trying to access mobile calendar in Salesforce1 application. Is there any possibility to access or sync device calendar in Salesforce1 application. Native Salesforce1 don't have any option to access calender through it.

Is it possible to access mobile calender in Salesforce1 application using phonegap or any other methods/library/frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that there is the "Today" feature.
It's one of the entries in the Salesforce1 menu on the native iOS / Android app and it should ask you to pull-in events from your device's calendar.

As to "real" calendar syncing between your device and your Salesforce calendar, that is something that indeed the Salesforce1 app doesn't do.
There are however many existing applications that will do calendar syncing.
This however will depend on the system you are using. (example, google calendar, outlook, lotus notes etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the Salesforce calendar, then you have full API access by querying/updating the `Event` sObject. You can easily fetch the running user's event list this way.

If you're referring to the native iOS or Android calendar, that's probably not available to you through SF1. You would be better-suited writing a native iOS or Android app that queries Salesforce for the `Event` list and then updates calendar items on the running device.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a way to view, create and edit events in salesforce1 through the calendar app which is available to install on appexchange. Name of the app is: ZakCalendar. Try it today, the app is available for free.

Thanks!

Comment: Please correct "salesforce 1" to "salesforce1".  It's too small an edit for me to make, but it will show up in searcheds properly this way.